# Does Spring Cloud Gateway and Swagger have compatibility issue, getting errors

Tags: spring-boot, microservices, swagger-2.0, spring-cloud-gateway

I am doing hands-on with creating microservices with Spring Cloud Gateway and Swagger. Unable to start my application. It is giving **Failed to introspect annotated methods on class springfox.documentation.swagger2.configuration.Swagger2DocumentationConfiguration** error which needs **spring-boot-starter-web** dependency. But on including this dependency, getting error **Spring MVC found on classpath, which is incompatible with Spring Cloud Gateway at this time. Please remove spring-boot-starter-web dependency.**

Can't we use Swagger with Spring Cloud Gateway?

**1st Microservice:**

**Code**

**pom.xml:**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.4.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>SCG</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>SCG</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Cloud Gateway having two MS.</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>Hoxton.SR8</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
         <dependency> <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId> <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId> 
            </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-gateway</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

**SPringCloudConfig**:

```
   package com.ashish.mongo1.config;

import org.springframework.cloud.gateway.route.RouteLocator;
import org.springframework.cloud.gateway.route.builder.RouteLocatorBuilder;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.reactive.config.ResourceHandlerRegistry;

@Configuration
public class SPringCloudConfig {

    @Bean
    public RouteLocator gatewayRoutes(RouteLocatorBuilder builder) {
        return builder.routes()
                .route(r -> r.path("/ms/ms2")
                        .uri("http://localhost:8081/")
                        .id("firstMS"))
                .build();
    }
    
}
```

**Bootstrap class:**

```
    package com.ashish.mongo1;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;

import springfox.documentation.builders.PathSelectors;
import springfox.documentation.builders.RequestHandlerSelectors;
import springfox.documentation.service.ApiInfo;
import springfox.documentation.spi.DocumentationType;
import springfox.documentation.spring.web.plugins.Docket;
import springfox.documentation.swagger2.annotations.EnableSwagger2;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableSwagger2
public class ScgApplication {
    
    RestTemplate rt;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ScgApplication.class, args);
    }

    public RestTemplate restTemplate() {
        return new RestTemplate();
    }
    
    @Bean
    public Docket swaggerConfiguration() {
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
                .select()
                .paths(PathSelectors.ant("/ms/*"))
                .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage("com.ashish.mongo1"))
                .build()
                .apiInfo(apiInfo());
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    private ApiInfo apiInfo() {
        return new ApiInfo(
                "Microservice 2", 
                "Sample API for Swagger Use", 
                "1.0", 
                "Free to use", 
                "Ashish Kumar", 
                "API License", 
                "http://localhost:8080/ms/ms2");
    }
}
```

**Controller:**

```
    package com.ashish.mongo1.controller;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/ms")
public class FirstMSResource {

    RestTemplate rt = restTemplate();
    @GetMapping("/ms1")
    public String firstMS() {
        String s = rt.getForObject("http://localhost:8081/ms/ms2", String.class);
        return "MS-1 called...."+s;
    }
    
    public RestTemplate restTemplate() {
        return new RestTemplate();
    }
}
```

**2nd Microservice:**

**pom.xml:**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.4.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>SCG</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>SCG</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Cloud Gateway having two MS.</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>Hoxton.SR8</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

**application.yml:**

```
server:
  port: 8081
```

**Controller:**

```
    package com.ashish.mongo1.controller;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/ms")
public class SecondMSResource {

    @GetMapping("/ms2")
    public String firstMS() {
        return "MS-2 called....";
    }
}
```

**Bootstrap class:**

```
    package com.ashish.mongo1;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;

import springfox.documentation.builders.PathSelectors;
import springfox.documentation.builders.RequestHandlerSelectors;
import springfox.documentation.service.ApiInfo;
import springfox.documentation.spi.DocumentationType;
import springfox.documentation.spring.web.plugins.Docket;
import springfox.documentation.swagger2.annotations.EnableSwagger2;

    @SpringBootApplication
    @EnableSwagger2
    public class ScgApplication {
    
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            SpringApplication.run(ScgApplication.class, args);
        }
        
        @Bean
        public Docket swaggerConfiguration() {
            return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
                    .select()
                    .paths(PathSelectors.ant("/ms/*"))
                    .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage("com.ashish.mongo1"))
                    .build()
                    .apiInfo(apiInfo());
        }
    
        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        private ApiInfo apiInfo() {
            return new ApiInfo(
                    "Microservice 2", 
                    "Sample API for Swagger Use", 
                    "1.0", 
                    "Free to use", 
                    "Ashish Kumar", 
                    "API License", 
                    "http://localhost:8080/ms/ms2");
        }
    
    }
```

getting following error on running the application:

```
2020-10-24 23:06:16.500  INFO 19896 --- [  restartedMain] com.ashish.mongo1.ScgApplication         : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2020-10-24 23:06:17.520  INFO 19896 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.cloud.context.scope.GenericScope     : BeanFactory id=863b9547-dc4a-3869-8a25-0fd2918e238c
2020-10-24 23:06:17.992  INFO 19896 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2020-10-24 23:06:18.002  INFO 19896 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2020-10-24 23:06:18.002  INFO 19896 --- [  restartedMain] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.38]
2020-10-24 23:06:18.135  INFO 19896 --- [  restartedMain] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2020-10-24 23:06:18.135  INFO 19896 --- [  restartedMain] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1622 ms
2020-10-24 23:06:18.483  INFO 19896 --- [  restartedMain] pertySourcedRequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped URL path [/v2/api-docs] onto method [springfox.documentation.swagger2.web.Swagger2Controller#getDocumentation(String, HttpServletRequest)]
2020-10-24 23:06:18.527  WARN 19896 --- [  restartedMain] GatewayClassPathWarningAutoConfiguration : 

**********************************************************

**Spring MVC found on classpath, which is incompatible with Spring Cloud Gateway at this time. Please remove spring-boot-starter-web dependency.**

**********************************************************


WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.springframework.cglib.core.ReflectUtils (file:/C:/Users/send2/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-core/5.2.9.RELEASE/spring-core-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar) to method java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(java.lang.String,byte[],int,int,java.security.ProtectionDomain)
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.springframework.cglib.core.ReflectUtils
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
2020-10-24 23:06:18.956  WARN 19896 --- [  restartedMain] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'routeDefinitionRouteLocator' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/gateway/config/GatewayAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'routeDefinitionRouteLocator' parameter 1; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'modifyRequestBodyGatewayFilterFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/gateway/config/GatewayAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'modifyRequestBodyGatewayFilterFactory' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.http.codec.ServerCodecConfigurer' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
2020-10-24 23:06:18.958  INFO 19896 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2020-10-24 23:06:18.973  INFO 19896 --- [  restartedMain] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2020-10-24 23:06:19.141 ERROR 19896 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   : 

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Parameter 0 of method modifyRequestBodyGatewayFilterFactory in org.springframework.cloud.gateway.config.GatewayAutoConfiguration required a bean of type 'org.springframework.http.codec.ServerCodecConfigurer' that could not be found.


Action:

**Consider defining a bean of type 'org.springframework.http.codec.ServerCodecConfigurer' in your configuration.**
```

and

After removing the **spring-boot-starter-web** dependency, getting following error:

```
    Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2020-10-24 23:29:05.719 ERROR 19676 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to process import candidates for configuration class [com.ashish.mongo1.ScgApplication]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect annotated methods on class springfox.documentation.swagger2.configuration.Swagger2DocumentationConfiguration
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processImports(ConfigurationClassParser.java:610) ~[spring-context-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.doProcessConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:311) ~[spring-context-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:250) ~[spring-context-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:207) ~[spring-context-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:175) ~[spring-context-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:319) ~[spring-context-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:236) ~[spring-context-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:280) ~[spring-context-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:96) ~[spring-context-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:707) ~[spring-context-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:533) ~[spring-context-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.reactive.context.ReactiveWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ReactiveWebServerApplicationContext.java:62) ~[spring-boot-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar:2.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:758) ~[spring-boot-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar:2.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:750) ~[spring-boot-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar:2.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) ~[spring-boot-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar:2.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) ~[spring-boot-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar:2.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1237) ~[spring-boot-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar:2.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226) ~[spring-boot-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar:2.3.4.RELEASE]
    at com.ashish.mongo1.ScgApplication.main(ScgApplication.java:22) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) ~[spring-boot-devtools-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar:2.3.4.RELEASE]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: **Failed to introspect annotated methods on class springfox.documentation.swagger2.configuration.Swagger2DocumentationConfiguration**
    at org.springframework.core.type.StandardAnnotationMetadata.getAnnotatedMethods(StandardAnnotationMetadata.java:162) ~[spring-core-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.retrieveBeanMethodMetadata(ConfigurationClassParser.java:403) ~[spring-context-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.doProcessConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:326) ~[spring-context-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:250) ~[spring-context-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processImports(ConfigurationClassParser.java:600) ~[spring-context-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    ... 23 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect Class [springfox.documentation.swagger2.configuration.Swagger2DocumentationConfiguration] from ClassLoader [jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader@2626b418]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:481) ~[spring-core-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:455) ~[spring-core-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.core.type.StandardAnnotationMetadata.getAnnotatedMethods(StandardAnnotationMetadata.java:151) ~[spring-core-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    ... 27 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/web/servlet/HandlerMapping
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:3244) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2387) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:463) ~[spring-core-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    ... 29 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.servlet.HandlerMapping
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:602) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522) ~[na:na]
    ... 33 common frames omitted
```

Comment: As far as I know, it should be possible to use Springfox with Spring Cloud. Feel free to raise a support issue [here](https://github.com/springfox/springfox/issues) in case you're stuck for a long time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@V.Mokrecov, I don't agree with you about Springfox support to SpringWebFlux.

Only following dependencies are sufficient for Springfox and SpringWebFlux:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

And with the release of Springfox 3.0.0, now there is no need to include annotations as well. You can omit @EnableSwagger2 and @EnableSwagger2WebFlux.

Including these dependencies worked for me.

The code implementing this can be found at [this link](https://github.com/AK1801/CentralisedSwagger/tree/master)

Answer (score 0):

Spring Cloud Gateway is built on Project Reactor and already contains a Netty (instead of Tomcat server).

So please try to remove:

```
<dependency> 
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId> 
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

And also Springfox does not yet support Spring Webflux, but there is a solution for it to work, for this you need to follow the steps described below.

Replace dependencies with the following:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
    <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
    <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
```

Add this dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
    <artifactId>springfox-spring-webflux</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
```

Add repositories:

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-milestone</id>
        <name>Spring Maven MILESTONE Repository</name>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-milestone</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>jcenter-snapshots</id>
        <name>jcenter</name>
        <url>http://oss.jfrog.org/artifactory/oss-snapshot-local/</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

Change the annotation to this:

```
@EnableSwagger2WebFlux
```

The working draft can be found at [this link](https://github.com/300kks/api-service).